# read complex json nested array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, nested

I have this json code

```
{
    "years": [{
        "id": 100531911,
        "year": 2012,
        "styles": [{
            "id": 101395591,
            "name": "LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)",
            "submodel": {
                "body": "Convertible",
                "modelName": "Camaro Convertible",
                "niceName": "convertible"
            },
            "trim": "LT"
        }]
    }],
    "warning": "VIN check sum validation failed. (check digit = 3, found = 9)",
    "matchingType": "SQUISHVIN",
    "MPG": {
        "highway": "28",
        "city": "17"
    }
}
```

I want to get Alert as `name:LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)` and `trim:LT`

How can I get this? I can get `year:2012` using

```
$.each(this,function(){
       Alert(this.year);
});
```

But I can't get name and trim(its another nested array of a nested array)
I user `$.each` twice.

My code is

```
$.each(this,function(){
  $.each(this,function(){
       alert(this.name);
       alert(this.trim);
  });
});
```

No output. Can u help me please?

Comment: As simple  {"years":[{"id":100531911,"year":2012,"styles": [{"id":101395591,"name":"LT 2dr Convertible w/2LT (3.6L 6cyl 6M)","submodel":{"body":"Convertible","modelName":"Camaro Convertible","niceName":"convertible"},"trim":"LT"}]}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access data like this

```
 alert(data.years[0].styles[0].name);
 alert(data.years[0].styles[0].trim);
```

assuming your jsondata is in data variable